# How to hide wsdl in websphere traditional v8.0

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, websphere-7, websphere-portal

We have a soap service which is deployed in Websphere Traditioanl server v8.0.. whenever i hit serviceurl?wsdl it shows wsdl details. I need to stop being exposed. How can I disable it? I tried writing servlet class for this url but did not worked. Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: But the WSDL just describes how to call the service. If the service is exposed, I can't think of a reason the WSDL shouldn't be too.

Comment: Yes @dbreaux but we need to stop publishing it.. Could you please help me out here?

Comment: I know of no way to stop that, but I also don't think it would be correct to do so. Why do you think you need to?

Comment: @dbreaux I work for a bank.. and they don't want to publish wsdl file

Comment: @dbreaux there is no way to stop it?

Comment: My point is that the WSDL only reveals what the service can do. If the service is exposed, hiding the WSDL doesn't secure anything. There shouldn't be anything sensitive in the WSDL.

Comment: wsdl requests are always get requests, and ws invocations are always post requests, so putting a servlet filter in front that intercepts all get requests, or just the ones that end with wsdl or xsd would probably do what you need.

Comment: @BruceT. I tried adding filter.. but request is not even coming to that servlet..

Comment: I agree with @dbreaux here, what is the reason they want to keep exposing the service, but not expose the wsdl?  If it's for security reasons, then like dbreaux mentioned, it's not really more secure by not exposing the wsdl.  That being said, a Servlet Filter like mentioned above should work, also a redirect rule could work if that is an option.

Comment: this is the reason some restricted environments like banks, don't want the wsdl accesible CWE-651: Exposure of WSDL File Containing Sensitive Information https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/651.html

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, as per JAX-WS 2.2 specifications (5.2.2 Publishing), publishing WSDL and making it accessible by "?wsdl" is required. "Conformance (WSDL Publishing): An Endpoint that uses the SOAP 1.1/HTTP binding (see 10) MUST make its contract available as a WSDL 1.1 document at the publishing address suffixed with ”?WSDL” or ”?wsdl”."

Comment: This is too late, but is good to know for reference, basically what you are saying is correct, the WSDL MUST be available for clients, but you can make it available in local machine, for example in classpath, package the WSDL with your application sources or crate a client library and package in there. Why do that? according with the OWASP, expose the WSDL in public url is a security risk, you can read more in here https://owasp.org/www-pdf-archive/SecuringWebServices-RixGroenboom.pdf